# 3 way join with subqueries and multiple where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve a problem where when i run my query it just runs forever and doesn't execute when i have 3 where clauses, but if I only have 2 where clauses it executes totally fine.

```
SELECT top(1) 
    INV.SUBINVENTORY_CODE, INV.LOCATOR_CODE, INV.ITEM_CODE, dp.DESCRIPTION, dp.barcode1, dp.barcode2, INV.QTY,  
    dp.FROM_SUB_INVENTORY_CODE, dp.FROM_LOCATOR_CODE, INV.SUBINVENTORY_CODE, Inv.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, dp_hist.barcode1, 
    dp_hist.barcode2, dp_hist.DESCRIPTION,dp_hist.FROM_SUB_INVENTORY_CODE, dp_hist.FROM_LOCATOR_CODE 
FROM 
    INVENTORY AS INV FULL OUTER JOIN deliveries_picks_hist as dp_hist ON Inv.item_code = dp_hist.item_code 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    deliveries_picks AS dp ON dp_hist.item_code = dp.ITEM_CODE 
WHERE 
    INV.LOCATOR_CODE = 'BMS.S.T.G' and 
    (inv.ITEM_CODE in 
    ((select TOP(1) ITEM_CODE from deliveries_picks_hist where  BARCODE1 = '" & barcode & "' or BARCODE2 = '" & barcode & "' or inv.ITEM_CODE = 'ASM.EN.CD'), 
    (select TOP(1) ITEM_CODE from deliveries_picks where BARCODE1 = '" & barcode & "' or BARCODE2 = '" & barcode & "' or inv.ITEM_CODE = 'ASM.EN.CD')))
group by 
    INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, INV.LOCATOR_CODE, INV.ITEM_CODE, INV.QTY,  dp_hist.barcode1, dp_hist.barcode2, dp.DESCRIPTION, 
    dp.FROM_LOCATOR_CODE,  dp.FROM_SUB_INVENTORY_CODE, INV.SUBINVENTORY_CODE, DP.BARCODE1, DP.BARCODE2, dp_hist.DESCRIPTION,
    dp_hist.FROM_SUB_INVENTORY_CODE, dp_hist.FROM_LOCATOR_CODE 
order by 
    dp_hist.DESCRIPTION
```

when I add `inv.ITEM_CODE = 'ASM.EN.CD'` then the query doesn't work but if I were to switch out one of the inner joins and keep the `inv.ITEM_CODE = 'ASM.EN.CD'` then it also works fine, I have not been able to pin point the problem, i have reformatted and tried a few different ways to work it but not luck.

Comment: Looks like you have one too many closing parentheses at the end of the where clause.

Comment: No that's not it, but you do have some unnecessary ones. I have to use my PC for this so I'll be right back.

Comment: Can you explain more about the goal of the query and the data structure?  That would help with knowing how the query is intended to work and if it can be perform better if written differently.

Comment: Can you check what these two queries return? 
[ select TOP(1) ITEM_CODE from deliveries_picks_hist where  BARCODE1 = '" & barcode & "' or BARCODE2 = '" & barcode & "' or inv.ITEM_CODE = 'ASM.EN.CD' ]

AND 

[ select TOP(1) ITEM_CODE from deliveries_picks where  BARCODE1 = '" & barcode & "' or BARCODE2 = '" & barcode & "' or inv.ITEM_CODE = 'ASM.EN.CD' ]

Comment: @Atif That query won't run by itself because it's correlated on `INV`.

Comment: Yes they both return ASM.EN.CD

Comment: Oh wow yeah you are totally right. I have tried many variations though, that properly should have worked.

Comment: TommyGraffam have you tried @shawnt00 solution? That is actually the right way.

Comment: Yes I have tried this method.

Comment: So why the full outer join? Data examples might help.

Comment: Can you show us an execution plan of one that executes completely and an estimated plan for the query that runs forever?

Comment: @TommyGraffam did you figure this out? I'm very curious to see the solution.

Comment: @Michael Z. I did figure out a way which makes it faster and works well I basically added some if statements in my VB onje if statement with the barcodes the elseif statement with the item_code it is working well. Thank you so much for your help though! You guys really got my brain juices working to figure out a good solution and all of your input did end up helping me in my final resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that what you wanted was what I have below. You're wanting to keep `INV` rows where `ITEM_CODE` is equal to `ASM.EN.CD` regardless of the `deliveries_picks*` lookup.

`OR`s are generally going to slow down a query. But I think the reason for the slow-down here is most likely because including the extra condition in the subqueries caused a lot more rows to match since it was correlated on an outer table (`INV`). In other words, *all* the rows in the subquery tables are going to pass the filter when that extra condition is true. The optimizer might not have made a plan that leverages the fact you only wanted to look at the "first" one.

Note that you do potentially have a problem when using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` in those subqueries. There really isn't a first row without one. And by the way, your use of full joins seems suspicious to me as do all the grouping columns. If you can describe the table relationships it's possible you'll get a much better query. Finally those "barcode" conditions might be simpler as `@barcode in (BARCODE1, BARCODE2)` so you don't have to repeat the concatenation.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    INV.SUBINVENTORY_CODE, INV.LOCATOR_CODE, INV.ITEM_CODE,
    dp.DESCRIPTION, dp.barcode1, dp.barcode2, INV.QTY,  
    dp.FROM_SUB_INVENTORY_CODE, dp.FROM_LOCATOR_CODE,
    INV.SUBINVENTORY_CODE, Inv.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, dp_hist.barcode1, 
    dp_hist.barcode2, dp_hist.DESCRIPTION,
    dp_hist.FROM_SUB_INVENTORY_CODE, dp_hist.FROM_LOCATOR_CODE 
FROM 
    INVENTORY AS INV
    FULL OUTER JOIN deliveries_picks_hist AS dp_hist ON Inv.item_code = dp_hist.item_code 
    FULL OUTER JOIN deliveries_picks AS dp ON dp_hist.item_code = dp.ITEM_CODE 
WHERE 
    INV.LOCATOR_CODE = 'BMS.S.T.G'
    AND INV.ITEM_CODE in (
        (
            select TOP 1 ITEM_CODE from deliveries_picks_hist
            where BARCODE1 = '" & barcode & "' or BARCODE2 = '" & barcode & "'
        ),    
        (
            select TOP 1 ITEM_CODE from deliveries_picks
            where BARCODE1 = '" & barcode & "' or BARCODE2 = '" & barcode & "'
        ),
        'ASM.EN.CD'
    )
group by 
    INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, INV.LOCATOR_CODE, INV.ITEM_CODE, INV.QTY,
    dp_hist.barcode1, dp_hist.barcode2, dp.DESCRIPTION, 
    dp.FROM_LOCATOR_CODE,  dp.FROM_SUB_INVENTORY_CODE,
    INV.SUBINVENTORY_CODE, DP.BARCODE1, DP.BARCODE2, dp_hist.DESCRIPTION,
    dp_hist.FROM_SUB_INVENTORY_CODE, dp_hist.FROM_LOCATOR_CODE 
order by 
    dp_hist.DESCRIPTION
```

Using `CASE` should work to "defer" execution of the subqueries if that doesn't work:

```
    AND
    CASE
        WHEN INV.ITEM_CODE = 'ASM.EN.CD' THEN 1
        WHEN INV.ITEM_CODE IN (
            (
                select TOP 1 ITEM_CODE from deliveries_picks_hist
                where BARCODE1 = '" & barcode & "' or BARCODE2 = '" & barcode & "'
            ),    
            (
                select TOP 1 ITEM_CODE from deliveries_picks
                where BARCODE1 = '" & barcode & "' or BARCODE2 = '" & barcode & "'
            )
        ) THEN 1
    END = 1
```

My guess is that this is your intention on the join logic:

```
FROM 
    INVENTORY AS INV LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        deliveries_picks AS dp
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        deliveries_picks_hist AS dp_hist
            ON dp_hist.ITEM_CODE = dp.ITEM_CODE
    )
        ON INV.ITEM_CODE = COALESCE(dp.ITEM_CODE, dp_hist.ITEM_CODE)
```

Normally when you see a full join you'll also see a bunch of `COALESCE()` operations.

Comment: @Tommy I'm glad you finally found something that works!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to build the filter into the joins. Try it out

```
SELECT TOP(1) INV.subinventory_code, 
              INV.locator_code, 
              INV.item_code, 
              dp.description, 
              dp.barcode1, 
              dp.barcode2, 
              INV.qty, 
              dp.from_sub_inventory_code, 
              dp.from_locator_code, 
              INV.subinventory_code, 
              Inv.inventory_item_id, 
              dp_hist.barcode1, 
              dp_hist.barcode2, 
              dp_hist.description, 
              dp_hist.from_sub_inventory_code, 
              dp_hist.from_locator_code 
FROM   inventory AS INV 
       FULL OUTER JOIN deliveries_picks_hist AS dp_hist 
                    ON Inv.item_code = dp_hist.item_code 
                       AND ( dp_hist.barcode1 = '" & barcode & "' 
                              OR dp_hist.barcode2 = '" & barcode & "'
                              OR inv.item_code = 'ASM.EN.CD' ) 
       FULL OUTER JOIN deliveries_picks AS dp 
                    ON dp_hist.item_code = dp.item_code 
                       AND ( dp.barcode1 = '" & barcode & "' 
                              OR dp.barcode2 = '" & barcode & "'
                              OR inv.item_code = 'ASM.EN.CD' ) 
WHERE  INV.locator_code = 'BMS.S.T.G'  
GROUP  BY INV.inventory_item_id, 
          INV.locator_code, 
          INV.item_code, 
          INV.qty, 
          dp_hist.barcode1, 
          dp_hist.barcode2, 
          dp.description, 
          dp.from_locator_code, 
          dp.from_sub_inventory_code, 
          INV.subinventory_code, 
          DP.barcode1, 
          DP.barcode2, 
          dp_hist.description, 
          dp_hist.from_sub_inventory_code, 
          dp_hist.from_locator_code 
ORDER  BY dp_hist.description
```

Or maybe Filter the tables first before joining using CTE

```
WITH hist 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   deliveries_picks_hist dp_hist 
         WHERE  dp_hist.barcode1 = '" & barcode & "' 
                 OR dp_hist.barcode2 = '" & barcode & "'
                 OR dp_hist.item_code = 'ASM.EN.CD'), 
     picks 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   deliveries_picks dp 
         WHERE  dp.barcode1 = '" & barcode & "' 
                 OR dp.barcode2 = '" & barcode & "'
                 OR dp.item_code = 'ASM.EN.CD') 
SELECT TOP(1) INV.subinventory_code, 
              INV.locator_code, 
              INV.item_code, 
              dp.description, 
              dp.barcode1, 
              dp.barcode2, 
              INV.qty, 
              dp.from_sub_inventory_code, 
              dp.from_locator_code, 
              INV.subinventory_code, 
              Inv.inventory_item_id, 
              dp_hist.barcode1, 
              dp_hist.barcode2, 
              dp_hist.description, 
              dp_hist.from_sub_inventory_code, 
              dp_hist.from_locator_code 
FROM   inventory AS INV 
       FULL OUTER JOIN hist AS dp_hist 
                    ON Inv.item_code = dp_hist.item_code 
       FULL OUTER JOIN picks AS dp 
                    ON dp_hist.item_code = dp.item_code 
WHERE  INV.locator_code = 'BMS.S.T.G' 
       AND inv.item_code = 'ASM.EN.CD' 
GROUP  BY INV.inventory_item_id, 
          INV.locator_code, 
          INV.item_code, 
          INV.qty, 
          dp_hist.barcode1, 
          dp_hist.barcode2, 
          dp.description, 
          dp.from_locator_code, 
          dp.from_sub_inventory_code, 
          INV.subinventory_code, 
          DP.barcode1, 
          DP.barcode2, 
          dp_hist.description, 
          dp_hist.from_sub_inventory_code, 
          dp_hist.from_locator_code 
ORDER  BY dp_hist.description
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this could accomplish the same as your original, but I don't know how efficient. Do you have indexes?

Comment: @Tommy Graffam I don't know if this is right, but it's worth a shot. I'm just really curious now what is up with your query. Are you sure you need Full Outer Joins?

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Z

Here is an example this works fine

```
 SELECT TOP(1) INV.subinventory_code,
          INV.locator_code,
          INV.item_code,
          dp.description,
          dp.barcode1,
          dp.barcode2,
          INV.qty,
          dp.from_sub_inventory_code,
          dp.from_locator_code,
          INV.subinventory_code,
          Inv.inventory_item_id,
          dp_hist.barcode1,
          dp_hist.barcode2,
          dp_hist.description,
          dp_hist.from_sub_inventory_code,
          dp_hist.from_locator_code
FROM   inventory AS INV
   FULL OUTER JOIN deliveries_picks_hist AS dp_hist
                ON Inv.item_code = dp_hist.item_code
   FULL OUTER JOIN deliveries_picks AS dp
                ON inv.item_code = dp.item_code
WHERE  INV.locator_code = 'BMS.S.T.G'
   AND ( inv.item_code = (SELECT TOP(1) item_code
                          FROM   deliveries_picks_hist
                          WHERE  barcode1 = ''
                                  OR barcode2 = '')
          OR inv.item_code = 'ASM.EN.CD' )
GROUP  BY INV.inventory_item_id,
      INV.locator_code,
      INV.item_code,
      INV.qty,
      dp_hist.barcode1,
      dp_hist.barcode2,
      dp.description,
      dp.from_locator_code,
      dp.from_sub_inventory_code,
      INV.subinventory_code,
      DP.barcode1,
      DP.barcode2,
      dp_hist.description,
      dp_hist.from_sub_inventory_code,
      dp_hist.from_locator_code
ORDER  BY Max(dp.createtime) DESC
```

and so does this

```
   SELECT TOP(1) INV.subinventory_code, 
          INV.locator_code, 
          INV.item_code, 
          dp.description, 
          dp.barcode1, 
          dp.barcode2, 
          INV.qty, 
          dp.from_sub_inventory_code, 
          dp.from_locator_code, 
          INV.subinventory_code, 
          Inv.inventory_item_id, 
          dp_hist.barcode1, 
          dp_hist.barcode2, 
          dp_hist.description, 
          dp_hist.from_sub_inventory_code, 
          dp_hist.from_locator_code 
FROM   inventory AS INV 
   FULL OUTER JOIN deliveries_picks_hist AS dp_hist 
                ON Inv.item_code = dp_hist.item_code 
   FULL OUTER JOIN deliveries_picks AS dp 
                ON dp_hist.item_code = dp.item_code 
WHERE  INV.locator_code = 'BMS.S.T.G' 
   AND ( inv.item_code IN (SELECT TOP(1) item_code 
                           FROM   deliveries_picks_hist 
                           WHERE  barcode1 = '" & barcode & "' 
                                   OR barcode2 = '" & barcode & "' 
                           UNION ALL 
                           SELECT TOP(1) item_code 
                           FROM   deliveries_picks 
                           WHERE  barcode1 = '" & barcode & "' 
                                   OR barcode2 = '" & barcode & "') ) 
GROUP  BY INV.inventory_item_id, 
      INV.locator_code, 
      INV.item_code, 
      INV.qty, 
      dp_hist.barcode1, 
      dp_hist.barcode2, 
      dp.description, 
      dp.from_locator_code, 
      dp.from_sub_inventory_code, 
      INV.subinventory_code, 
      DP.barcode1, 
      DP.barcode2, 
      dp_hist.description, 
      dp_hist.from_sub_inventory_code, 
      dp_hist.from_locator_code 
ORDER  BY dp_hist.description
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure of your issue. Does your query not return the results you want or does it execute slower than you had expected? Maybe it's generating an error? Please give me more info. Without seeing the tables we're going to need more info.

Comment: It literally stays on Executing Query... and doesn't ever execute it gets stuck.

Comment: I need it to work with all three where clauses but will only work with two of them. but I can pick any two and it'll work with them. but if i add a third, it brain farts and i cannot figure out why.

Comment: So the only thing is the last part of the two sub queries? You're saying that keeping three there does not work, but going to any two works?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct, Michael i really appreciate your help. I have been trying to get this to work for quite some time, and I finally decided, alright that's it! I'm going to Stack. =]

Comment: Look closely at your Where. Specifically the IN. It wants to filter on `inv.item_code` and it does so with another query filtering on `inv.item_code`. It's confused and f%$*. You can't write it like that.

Comment: I think I can write some of that filter into a join. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Tommy. Are you saying that my query wouldn't complete either? I threw out another suggestion using `case`.

Comment: Yeah I realized that, that was a fluke my original code that I had created (which failed) was almost identical to shawnt00's.